# Como fazer um filtro de seleção de bit flags?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Sou novato em banco de dados e estou participando de um projeto em Oracle-SQL onde preciso criar um filtro de seleção de flags numa coluna que armazena as flags como ativas ou não a partir da posição de cada caractere de números binários, o que *aparentemente* é chamado de bit flag.

Por exemplo:

Numa hipotética situação de 4 flags, a coluna *Flag* armazenaria os números assim:

- **11**, para o caso das flags 1 e 2 ativas;
- **1100**, para o caso das flags 3 e 4 ativas;
- **1111**, para o caso de todas as flags ativas;
- **0**, para nenhuma flag ativa;

Através de SQL (Oracle), como posso manipular esses números a fim de saber, por exemplo, se a flag 3 está ativa, tendo em mente que outras flags podem estar ativas e que essa tabela tem uma grande quantidade de elementos a percorrer?

Comment: Não seria melhor fazer por posição ? 0010 , 3 ativa , 1101 1,2 e 4 ativas ? Mas o melhor seria normalizar isto , veja Formas Normais de Banco de Dados.

Comment: A sua sugestão faz todo o sentido, mas o problema é que eu não posso fazer nenhuma alteração no banco.

Answer (score 0):

Para quem tiver o mesmo problema que o meu, resolvi através do uso da função SUBSTR do SQL, aliada ao parâmetro da posição recebendo valor negativo para inverter a posição inicial.

Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA_COM_FLAGS
WHERE SUBSTR(COLUNA_FLAG, -1, 1) = 1
```

retorna todos os elementos em que o primeiro binário (ou seja, o último dígito do número) da COLUNA_FLAG esteja ativo.

Mais informações [neste link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462061/sql-server-substring-position-negative-value).